# Excel Formula for Progress shading based on percentage

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, gantt-chart

I want my gantt chart to have a "show progress" option and shade the pink bars with a dark blue. The main columns I'm working with are start date, end date, work days, and percentage complete.

```
**For reference**
start_date: =Gantt!$I18
end_date: =Gantt!$J18
workdays: =Gantt!$H14
percentage_complete: =Gantt!$K18

**Name that isn't working**
item_in_complete: 
    =AND(Gantt!date>=Gantt!start_date, 
     Gantt!date<=WORKDAY(Gantt!start_date,    
     Gantt!percentage_complete*Gantt!workdays-1))

**Formatting Rule**
 =AND(show_progress="Yes", item_in_complete)
```

I'm able to shade the "timelines" of the tasks on my chart so I know the beginning of my "item_in_complete" formula is correct. I'm doing something wrong with the second half of the formula and the percentage calculation. (I'm only working with Monday - Friday dates.

[text]([screenshot of what shows right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFPus.png))

The gantt chart is only shading the number of days based on the 100s of percent complete. For example, if I type 100% complete, 1 bar from the start_date is shaded, 200% is two bars etc. rather than all 5 of the work_days (0r 3 if the number of work_days is 6 and the percentage_complete is 50%)

[Conditional Formatting Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6LDt.png)
[gantt chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgXfE.png)

Comment: Your item_in_complete formula works for me but where are you storing it? In the conditional format?

Comment: I concur with @Grant, your item_in_complete formula appears to be working fine. The problem most likely lies with the order logic of your conditional formatting rules. For example, if the rule to shade the date range area pink is something like `=AND(Gantt!date>=Gantt!start_date, Gantt!date<=Gantt!end_date)`, then the new rule to shade the progress portion blue should be applied first. Don't use the "Stop if True" option either. Just try changing the order in which the rules are applied to get the appropriate combination of colors appearing.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I was able to get the dark blue shading to show. However, the gantt chart is now only shading the number of days based on the 100s of percent complete. For example, if I type 100% complete, 1 bar from the start_date is shaded, 200% is two bars etc. rather than all 5 of the work_days.

Comment: If possible, could you please edit the original question and add a screenshot of your conditional formatting rules, with the formulas you’re using? I have an old Gantt chart I made years ago using similar logic… I’ll try to find time to share it later today.

Comment: Will do, editing now! Thank you

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. Thanks everyone!